# How to do I get my projects to be in a seperate branch on GitHub?

Tags: git

I recently tried to get a project on Heroku then deleted it. But now every project I create has the same saves and edits as all the files I use. Its hard to describe but here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you created a repository in `~/Desktop`? Normally you'd want to create a repository in each project directory.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with Heroku or GitHub. This is a local repository.

Comment: Ok thanks Chris, I must of done this by mistake. Will removing the repository mess with my other projects?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "other projects" :-).

Comment: Sorted it now Chris, thanks!